# NSString property from textview disappear

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I have a view that through a prepareSeque method should pass whatever is written in a textView to the next view. 
Before I had textField and textfield.text in the seque method worked fine. But I can not get it to work with a textView.

I have a NSString property in the .h file: @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textString; 
I syntesize it in the .m file: @synthesize textString =_textString;

In my textViewDidEndEditing i can see (through debug) that the text in the text View is picked up and that the textString is set.

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  NSString *theText = textView.text;
  self.textString =theText;
  }

However, when I then want to retrieve the textString in my Seque method it does not contain any text:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"go"]) {

    ISecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    vc.funnyString = self.textString;
}
```

If i enter: self.textString =@"Hi Hi"; in the Seque method funnyString will be passed with Hi Hi so that part works fine.

Have I just totally misunderstood the "get and set" of NSString in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you have been using a `weak` property for `textString` so it will be `nil` when the scope of your property get out of your `textViewDidEndEditing` method.

Why? because the principle of weak reference is that it will be set to `nil` as soon as the object you are referring to doesn't exist anymore. This will be the case for the "`theText`" object which won't exist at the end of your method. Use a `strong` property instead.

Comment: Thank you, that solved that part of it.
Would you also be able to tell me why I can not use the textView.text in my sequeMethod just like I used the textField.text before.

If you push the button that activates the prepareSegue method now before you press done on keyboard (which activates DidEndEdit) the String is not set.

Comment: did u check if textView is not nil?

Comment: No, I did now thought and yes it seems to be nil. I thought the syntesization would take care of that? Or howcome it is nil?

I acctually would like the cursor to be in the textView and the keyboard to display directly so perhaps I could update textViewShouldBeginEditing to accomplish that and avoid the nil issue!?!

Comment: Setting the textstring property to strong worked fine but setting the textview property to strong does not seem to do anything.

Comment: My referencing outlet collection in storyboard was set to view or not set at all, now it seem to be working fine!